Tomcat keeps showing infinity loop of login popup
Tomcat does not let me login although the username and password is correct
Hi. I have installed Tomcat 10 on my computer for Servlet application, when the setup popup show and asked me to input username and password, I put "admin" username and password. But when I tried to login to /manager/html, I typed "admin" for username and password, the login popup show again without any error, I type again and press Enter but it keeps showing infinite. What should I do now?
This is my configuration file:
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
<tomcat-users>


In your text you say you use "root" as username and your configuration file it's defined as "admin". See the problem?

Oh! I edited, the problem happens although I type correct credentials

You are missing the roles and the tomcat-users tag is not closing.
  <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
  </tomcat-users>

